# Updating an online symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, updates

Yesterday I uploaded my first symfony2 project to a **shared server**, what I did is traditional, I compressed the project to zip, and I uploaded it using firezilla, then extract it in the server, it took me some time to get it working online.

Today I want to made some updates on the code, and I need to apply these updates to the version I have only.

Is there anything that can I do to get this done without using firezilla again? I'm beginner with symfony2 and this is the first time I ever deployed a project.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to upload files to the server. You don't have to upload all files again, just the ones you changed. You can upload files automatically to your server if your IDE supports it (i.e. phpstorm).

Comment: So, I'm working with netbeans, does netbeans support this option?

Comment: looks like it does: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39197/ftpsitedeployer and https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/remote-hosting-and-ftp-account.html

Comment: And when working with symfony2, I have /app_dev.php and /app.php, do I have to make sure that my app.php is updated before uploading files again?

Comment: You don't need to worry about app.php file unless you make changes to it. According to symfony docs you should rarely worry about making changes to these files.

Comment: thank you so much userid53, I'm installing the pluging you said

Comment: If you happen to have ssh access to your server then you can just pull the changes from your git repository.  Of course, not all shared servers let you log on directly.  But I find it easier then the ftp stuff.

Comment: @Cerad, Thank you dear, I don't have ssh access to my server... I already asked them about it and they said that I have to switch to another plan.

Comment: @Paziツ I'm going to give it a try :) thanks